# php define variable inside str_replace array

Tags: php, templates, replace

I have a template system, that replaces text such as `{HEADER}` with the appropriate content. I use an array like this, that replaces the key with the value using str_replace.

```
$array = array("HEADER","This is the header");
    foreach($array as $var => $content) {
       $template = str_replace("{" . strtoupper($var). "}", $content,$template);
    }
```

Now im trying to use a defined variable like this:

```
define("NAME","Site Name");
```

Inside the value for the header. So I want the defined variable to be inside the array which gets replaced so it would look like this, but it doesn't work.

```
$array = array("HEADER","Welcome to ".NAME."'s website!");
```

Any ideas? tell me if im not clear

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what's happening? What do you see? Do you see any accompanying errors when error reporting is turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your array line be:

```
$array = array("HEADER" => "Welcome to ".NAME."'s website!");
```

Since you are accessing the array items by key and value?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are looping through the array, using :

```
foreach($array as $var => $content) {
    // ...
}
```

makes me think you should use an **associative array** for your `$array`.

i.e., it should be declared this way :

```
$array = array("HEADER" => "Welcome to ".NAME."'s website!");
```

And, as a demonstration, here's an example of code :

```
$template = <<<TPL
Hello, World !
{HEADER}
And here's the content ;-)
TPL;

define("NAME","Site Name");

$array = array("HEADER" => "Welcome to ".NAME."'s website!");
foreach($array as $var => $content) {
   $template = str_replace("{" . strtoupper($var). "}", $content,$template);
}

var_dump($template);
```

And the output I get it :

```
string 'Hello, World !
Welcome to Site Name's website!
And here's the content ;-)' (length=73)
```

Which indicates it's working ;-)

*(It wasn't, when `$array` was declared the way you set it)*

When using this :

```
$array = array("HEADER","This is the header");
var_dump($array);
```

You are declaring an array that contains two items :

```
array
  0 => string 'HEADER' (length=6)
  1 => string 'This is the header' (length=18)
```

On the other hand, when using this :

```
$array = array("HEADER" => "This is the header");
var_dump($array);
```

You are declaring an array that :

- contains only one item
- "HEADER" being the key
- and "This is the header" being the value

Which gives :

```
array
  'HEADER' => string 'This is the header' (length=18)
```

When using `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`, you need the second one ;-)

And, purely for reference, you can take a look at, in the manual, the following pages :

- [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [foreach](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: my bad i am using that sort of array, i just typed it on the fly here. yes i know how to use arrays and foreach..

Comment: does this mean your problem is solved ? Or is there still something that *doesn't work* ? If so, can you edit your question to add some informations to say more about what *doesn't work* mean ?